# How to add the mapview layers in Leaflet maps in r shiny app?

Tags: r, leaflet, rendering, shiny, mapview

```
server <- function(input, output){
output$map <-renderLeaflet({   
df_data <- uploadshapefile()
...
df_data <- as.data.frame(df_data)
    df_data@data$


id <- nrow(df_data)
    lm.palette <- colorRampPalette(c("red","white","blue","blue4"), space = "rgb")
    m <- mapview(df_data, zcol="quadrant",
            col.regions = lm.palette(20), map = NULL,
            main = "Local Moran's I", pretty = T) 
 })        
 output$clustered_map <- renderLeaflet({
      m <- m()
      m@map 
    })
}
```

This is the server part of my app, here I cannot get the mapview properly. i.e. I cannot view the base layers with my map. there is no base layers in my leaflet mapview but zoom in, zoom out and panning data is possible. I also followed this [link](https://github.com/r-spatial/mapview/issues/39). But no use. I want to get the solution.